# How to update a go template while still persisting the original template variables

Tags: templates, go, command-line-interface

This is a high level question, as I'm not sure how to approach this problem:

I'm building a CLI that sets up code projects for users automatically.

I want to create an `update` feature that will allow the user to update to the latest CLI's template versions but still keep the original variables they used to create the project (i.e. project name, env variables, etc...)

I know how to create new templates, but I don't know how I could update and still keep the variables passed by the user.

It would be something similar to a git merge, so merge the user's local project with the updated CLI template.

In the code below you can see an example of how the files are templated with `var deploymentYamlData` as string variables

I have a function that organizes all these file templates into the proper directory structure for the project.

How would I go about merging directory templates with the user's local directory, while being able to persist the original template variables?

Apologies ahead of time if I need to clarify more.

```
package main

import (
    "text/template"
        "os"
)

var deploymentYamlData = `---

  # do not edit commented lines
  # CLI-Version: {{ .GitTagVersion}}

  app: {{ .BotName }}
  type: web
  team: {{ .TeamName }}
  docker_image: {{ .DockerImageName }}
  docker_tag: {{ .TagVersion }}
  internal: false
  replicas: {{ .Replicas }}
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  container_port: {{ .DockerImagePort }}
   healthcheck:
    path: /{{ .DockerImageHealthCheck }}
  dynamodb:
    enable_deleteitem: true
    tables:
      - name: {{ .BotName }}_conversation_data
`

type DigitalAssistant struct {
    BotName string
    TeamName string
    DockerImageName string
    TagVersion string
    Replicas int
    DockerImagePort int
    DockerImageHealthCheck string
        GitTageVersion string

}

func main() {
    bot := DigitalAssistant{"bobisyouruncle", "teamAwesome", "awesomebotimagename", "0.1.0", 1, 8000, "health"}
    bmap, err := template.New("captain.tmpl").Parse(deploymentYamlData)
    if err != nil { panic(err) }
    err = bmap.Execute(os.Stdout, bot)
    if err != nil { panic(err) }
}
```

Comment: You can't really, you'll need to save the variables provided somewhere (e.g. maybe a JSON file alongside the generated files) so that you can re-use them when re-executing the templates. Once the template is executed, there are no variables to preserve - it's just raw text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this, but this roundtrip will be easier if you generate and read YAML using a module like https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml rather than using templates.

Also, this tool will make it easy to make the struct type by example: https://mengzhuo.github.io/yaml-to-go/

A different parsing approach is done in https://github.com/spf13/viper which might be more useful if you allow fields you don´t know.